# MySQL Selecting and expressions with enums

Tags: mysql

I do a lot of queries of the form

```
SELECT `u` AS `A`, `v` as B, TRUE AS `IsFirst`, FALSE AS `IsSecond` from `first`
UNION
SELECT `x` AS `A`, `y` AS B, FALSE AS `IsFirst`, TRUE as `IsSecond` from `second`
```

and such, usually make them into views of course.

Rather than having a bunch of columns with bools in them I'd rather like to use an ENUM, I have thought about using integer values rather than separate columns but this could lead to errors (the row names are self explanatory, a column called `Source` with value `2` isn't) and I don't want to use strings for obvious reasons.

I'd like to use an `ENUM`, but I don't know (nor can I find if you even can) write a `SELECT` with an enum expression. I've tried the obvious:

```
SELECT CAST("A", ENUM("A","B"));
SELECT CAST(1, ENUM("A","B"));
```

and some others that were also syntax errors, but they were from desperation and I didn't really have any hope. The MySQL docs list the types cast supports and ENUM is not one of them, the above was something I tried before I knew that.

I can keep using columns, its just an ENUM would be nicer.

Is there a syntax for this? (Perhaps from the view side?)

Answer (score -1):

[ENUM values are always strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html); the values given in the ENUM() definition must be quoted string literals, and casts are handled automatically by MySQL where necessary. (Technically, you can specify integer literals in an ENUM() definition, but it won't work like you expect; see the linked documentation page for details.)

Thus:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id serial, 
                   foo ENUM("A", "B") NOT NULL, 
                   bar ENUM("3", "4") NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) 
       VALUES ("A", 3), ("B", 4);

SELECT * FROM test;
+----+-----+-----+
| id | foo | bar |
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 |   A |   3 |
|  2 |   B |   4 |
+----+-----+-----+

SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM test WHERE foo = "A";
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM test WHERE bar = "4";
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

-- automatic cast from integer to string in the WHERE clause,
-- which reduces to the previous query and matches row with id 2
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM test WHERE bar = 4;
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because it creates a table, try "select 5;" as a query, I want to do something like this but rather than an integer, an enum member.

Comment: The table's only there as an example, and it's necessary in that context because ENUM only makes sense in a DDL statement, i.e., CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, and friends. ENUM in SELECT makes no sense, which is why it's a syntax error; once you've defined an ENUM column, what you get back from it is always a string (or NULL if you defined the column to permit that), and you can cast from there. (Your question isn't really clear, but if you're looking to deal with many booleans compactly, try a [BIT (bitfield) column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html).)